# adding text to an image, no canvas, vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, css, dom, appendchild

I am working on a meme generator project, it's to practice DOM manipulation. So, I'm supposed to use vanilla JavaScript and no canvas. I'm having trouble finding answer with these parameters. I am almost done with the project, I just need to add text to the picture that they submitted.

I have tried using innerText and innerHTML they seem to just replace it. I've tried append child, similar to how I got the appendchild with the image, but I either get an error or replace the image.

I was pretty sure that I needed to add it add the picture with JavaScript then style it with CSS. Maybe just add a class with classList.

```js
console.log('Currentfile: memegenerator');
let img = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      let UIurl = document.getElementById('picurl');
      let memeToBe = UIurl.value;

      let img = document.createElement('img');
      img.setAttribute('src', memeToBe);
      img.setAttribute('class', 'meme');

      // append to the document with set attribute using said variable
      let memeLocation = document.getElementById('location');
      memeLocation.appendChild(img);

      //url for pic test
      //https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360

      //add text to image
      //get text values
      let inputText = document.getElementById('text_top');
      let textValue = inputText.value;

      addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        let clickedElement = e.target;
        console.log(clickedElement);

        let targetCheck = clickedElement.classList.contains("meme");

        if (targetCheck) {
          clickedElement.remove();
        }
      })
```

```css
h1 {
  color: navy;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.main {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  border: 0.08rem solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.meme {
  width: 99%;
  /* margin: 2 auto; */
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  border: 0.08rem solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

main:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

meme:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

body {
  background-color: #f0feff;
}

.button {
  float: right;
}


/* divider styles */

hr.rounded {
  border-top: 2px solid #bbb;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 90%;
}

.border_lower {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 90%;
}


/* form styles */

form {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

form input {
  margin: 2px;
}

form label {
  margin: 2px;
}


/* Container holding the image and the text */

.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}


/* Bottom left text */

.bottom-left {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}


/* Top left text */

.location {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}
```

```html
<main class="main">
  <h1 class="center">MEME GENERATOR!</h1>
  <hr class="rounded" />
  <form action="#" class="form">
    <label for="text_top">Text Upper:</label>
    <input type="text" name="text_top" id="text_top" /><br />
    <label for="text_lower">Text Lower:</label>
    <input type="text" name="text_lower" id="text_lower" /><br />
    <label for="picturl">Picture:</label>
    <input type="url" name="picurl" id="picurl" /><br /><br /><br />
    <input class="button " type="submit" value="Add Meme:" /><br />
    <hr />
  </form>
  <div id="location"></div>
  <hr class="border_lower" />
  <p class="center"><small>Thanks for visiting!</small></p>
</main>
```

Comment: The question becomes, do you want the ability to SAVE the image after it has been created? And why no canvas?

Comment: You could add a `::before` pseudo-element, with your text as its `content` property to the img tag with CSS but you won't be able to save it as say a png file that way. Why don't you want to use canvas?

Comment: Im doing a self study course, they have'nt taught canvas yet; and, they gave the below link as a hint. But I've not quite sure how to paste said value on to a picture.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp

Comment: What exactly is your assignment? Are you supposed to render the meme on the server? Without a canvas you can not add text to an image in the browser. You can lay text on top of it, but it is not part of the image. So if you try to copy/safe the meme you'll lose the text.

Comment: Directions:
memegen. : a form that accepts a link to an image, text for the meme. upon submision , use JS  to append to the DOM a div which contains the meme, including the image and its text.

User should be able to submit a form on the page to generate a new meme on the page, and should be able to add multiple memes to the page by submitting the form multiple times. Users should be able to click on a button to remove a meme from the page. When the meme form is submitted, values in the form inputs should be cleared.
JS/HTML/CSS only

Comment: I skipped the button part, just realized that, I'll fix later. 

It technically doesn't say "no canvas" but why would they ask me to do something they haven't taught yet? 

Officially, they didn't say save the image, but I guess we could if it makes it easier.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: you are supposed to reduce the question to the simplest form, not dumping out 300 lines of code and let other people do your work

Comment: @JoshuaWolfe No, it it not simpler to use a canvas or save the image. It's a misunderstanding. Memes are images. A meme-generator takes one or multiple images and some texts and renders a new image that you can save, link-to etc. So you talking about memes made us think that that's what you're supposed to build; code to bake some text into an image. That's what led this conversation in this direction. Not trying to play the blame game, you're still learning. Just trying to point out that this is what happens when someone uses a "technical term" "wrong". And it happens all the time.

Comment: @nonopolarity - Somehow I missed that memo. Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: @ Thomas - I appreciate the and explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this isn't about saving the images but just for display purposes, I got it working.

The main problem that you were having is your approach seemed to focus more on the javascript side of things but missed out on the CSS part of it.

There are multiple ways to put images behind text, the most common two are:

1. Setting the images as a background image on the parent element (ie div) then just setting the text within that element
2. Using CSS to absolute position the text on the image and use z-index to layer them

For my answer I chose #2.

Besides misc code clean ups, the main function that I did was:

1. I created a div, and gave it a class of `meme`
2. I added the image to that div
3. I added the top and bottom text to their own divs and append those to the meme div
4. Using CSS, I positioned the top and bottom text above the image

A few other things, when adding an `eventListeners` unless it is absolutely needed, I recommend tying them to a specific element and not just the document (or nothing at all which I believe is document anyway). By applying it to the document, any click will be processed, but by tying it to the element, only clicks on that element will be processed.

```js
console.log('Currentfile: memegenerator');
let img = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
let form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let meme = document.createElement("div");
      let top_text = document.createElement("div");
      let bottom_text = document.createElement("div");
      let img = document.createElement("img");
      
      let btn = document.createElement("button");
      btn.setAttribute("type","button");
      
      img.src = document.getElementById('picurl').value;
      top_text.classList.add("top_text");
      top_text.innerHTML = document.getElementById('text_top').value;
      
      bottom_text.classList.add("bottom_text");
      bottom_text.innerHTML = document.getElementById('text_lower').value;
      
      btn.innerHTML = "REMOVE";
      
      meme.classList.add("meme");
      meme.appendChild(top_text);
      meme.appendChild(bottom_text);
      meme.appendChild(img);
      meme.appendChild(btn);
      
      let memeLocation = document.getElementById('location');
      memeLocation.appendChild(meme);

      document.getElementById('picurl').value = "";
      document.getElementById('text_top').value = "";
      document.getElementById('text_lower').value = "";

      btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          meme.remove();
      })
});
```

```css
h1 {
  color: navy;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.main {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  border: 0.08rem solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.meme {
  width: 99%;
  /* margin: 2 auto; */
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  border: 0.08rem solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  position:relative;
}

.top_text{
position:absolute;
top:10px;
left:30px;
color:#ffffff;
z-index:3
}

.bottom_text{
position:absolute;
bottom:20px;
left:30px;
color:#ffffff;
z-index:3
}

.meme img{
max-width:100%;
z-index:2
}

main:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

meme:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

body {
  background-color: #f0feff;
}

.button {
  float: right;
}


/* divider styles */

hr.rounded {
  border-top: 2px solid #bbb;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 90%;
}

.border_lower {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 90%;
}


/* form styles */

form {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

form input {
  margin: 2px;
}

form label {
  margin: 2px;
}


/* Container holding the image and the text */

.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}


/* Bottom left text */

.bottom-left {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}


/* Top left text */

.location {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}
```

```html
<main class="main">
  <h1 class="center">MEME GENERATOR!</h1>
  <hr class="rounded" />
  <form action="#" class="form">
    <label for="text_top">Text Upper:</label>
    <input type="text" name="text_top" id="text_top" /><br />
    <label for="text_lower">Text Lower:</label>
    <input type="text" name="text_lower" id="text_lower" /><br />
    <label for="picturl">Picture:</label>
    <input type="url" name="picurl" value="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" id="picurl" /><br /><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Add Meme:" /><br />
    <hr />
  </form>
  <div id="location"></div>
  <hr class="border_lower" />
  <p class="center"><small>Thanks for visiting!</small></p>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!! I was about to try positioning the text. Seeing this taught me I was heading in the right direction. :) :)